# How to subtract 10 Days from Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my solution to this:
Thank you for all of the suggestions and help. I ended up using moment.js and now this date situation is working as I needed. Here is what I did with moment.js:

```
var preorderdate = moment(date).subtract('days',10).format('MMMM D, YYYY');
var releasedate = moment(date).format('MMMM D, YYYY');
```

I renamed some of the variables but you can see that I took the date variable, subtracted 10 days and formatted it to February 12, 2014. I took a separate variable and just formatted it with moment.js. This script is pretty awesome. I never, ever would've found it without Pointy's suggestion. Thank you all so much!

I'm not a JS expert but I'm trying to subtract 10 days from a string of 'February 12, 2014' to no avail. So when I run my code, I'm trying to get it to display as 'February 2, 2014.'

```
function isbnPreOrder (isbn, date) {
    var date = 'February 12, 2014';
    var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate()-10;
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var predate = (m_names[curr_month]+" "+curr_date+", "+curr_year);
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding the following but it just returns this value 1391797140943:
var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * 10;
var predate= (d.setTime(d.getTime() - dateOffset));

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Make a Date instance:

```
var date = new Date("2014-02-12");
```

Then set its timestamp back by 10 days:

```
date.setDate( date.getDate() - 10 );
```

You cannot rely on browsers being able/willing to parse the date format "February 12, 2014".  If you have no choice at all in the date format, then you'll have to parse that yourself or use [a helper library](http://www.datejs.com/). ([Another possibility here.](http://momentjs.com/))

Comment: Sad but true, `Date.parse` is not reliable for formatting, momentjs is a great alternative though

Answer (score 2):

I'd modify your function to:

```
function isbnPreOrder (isbn, date) {
    var date = 'February 12, 2014';
    var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var predate = (m_names[curr_month]+" "+curr_date+", "+curr_year);
    var x = 10;
    predate.setDate(predate.getDate() - x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function isbnPreOrder (isbn, date) {
var date = 'February 12, 2014';
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",   "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.setDate(d.getDate()-10);
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var predate = (m_names[curr_month]+" "+curr_date+", "+curr_year);
```

Answer (score 0):

all is right except for one line. pass the `date` variable into your `Date` initialization.

```
var d = new Date(date);
```