# Subtract days from a date field(mm/dd/yyy) excluding weekends jquery

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker, weekend

How can I subtract days from a date field?

Example:

Date Value is **03/10/2014** (mm/dd/yy),

I want to be able to subtract 6 weedays from it to get **03/03/2014**

Can someone please help me get this.

Fiddle: to add 6 weekdays and disable all previous date values...
From this fiddle whatever date is selected 6 weekdays must be subtracted from it.

i.e `$("#txtFromDate").val() - 6 weekdays`
http://jsfiddle.net/7DHVr/8/

Thanks in advance

Comment: plz provide some code to get idea

Comment: `weedays` = week days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 var count = 10;
    //Add the 2 days of weekend in numer of days .
    var d = new Date();
    
    count = count + (parseInt(count/5))*2;
    d.setDate(d.getDate() -count);
    //suppose its ending on weekend day then increment them manually.
    if(d.getDay() == 6 ) d.setDate(d.getDate() -1); 
    if(d.getDay() == 0){ d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2);}; 
    alert(d);
```

it will substract all weekend day from whatever you want to substract day dynamically

Comment: what is the mistake in this code why remove from accepted answer

Comment: The issue is, the 'noofday' is variable... I wanted the newDate to be 03/03/2014 when 'noofday' is 6

Comment: got the point it will not work if in between 6 day there is sunday

Comment: Yeah, it is giving the same date, Do you have a solution ? Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48832/discussion-between-betrob-and-chirag-sutariya)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by subtracting from a Date type variable in javascript  like so

```
var d = new Date("08/18/2009");
d.setDate(d.getDate()-5);
```

This will return a string of numbers representing that date then use

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5))
```

If you want to reformat it as a date
the detailed answer is here [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, but I want it to subtract only week days

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer. You may want to use [DateJs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for easier use of date API.

So it would be like so:

```
 Date.today().addDays(-6)
```

To delete 6 weekdays you just need to do

```
new Date().last().week()  - this will substruct 5 weekdays
```

and then if it is weekday then substruct 1 additional, if its Saturday then 2, if Sunday - 3

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* accomplish this using the standard javascript `Date` object, I'd strongly recommend using a datetime library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) instead of trying to roll your own. Especially when you consider locale, timezones, leap years, months being different lengths, what day is start of week, etc.

Moment.js has weekday support and the documentation for it can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/).

To subtract 6 weekdays from a date, you can do the following:

`moment(date).weekday(-6);`

Note that you can pass moment an existing javascript `Date` as well as a wide variety of ISO date formats or even just an array with `[year, month, day, hour, minute, second]` in it. If you provide no date, moment will default to the current date and time.

More about what can be parsed can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Comment: Yes, that one seems even nicer than DateJS. +1