# How to get yesterday date in node.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-format

I am using **date-format** package in node back end and I can get today date using

```
var today = dateFormat(new Date());
```

In the same or some other way I want yesterday date. Still I did't get any proper method. For the time being I am calculating yesterday date manually with lot of code. Is there any other method other then writing manually ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: If we all could try to search first and post questions only if we don't find, that'd be great. And if we mark questions as duplicate instead of posting answers just to gain reps, that'd be great.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date(); // Today!
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // Yesterday!
```

Comment: what if the current date is 1st of January 2015? would yesterday still be equal to 31st December 2014 following this method?

Comment: @ChickenWing24 Yes, its.

Comment: I tried this. A `-1` on 1st of March makes it 31st of Feb. Definitely incorrect.

Comment: I tried it with Node.js v12.21.0 and see the correct result:


```
Welcome to Node.js v12.21.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let d = new Date('2020-03-01')
undefined
> new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1))
2020-02-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 7):

I would take a look at moment.js if you are interested in doing calculations with dates, there are many issues you can run into trying to do it manually or even with the built in Date objects in JavaScript/node.js such as leap years and daylight savings time issues.

http://momentjs.com/

For example:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
console.log(yesterday.format());
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var date=new Date();
var date=new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-1));
console.log(date);
```

This will give you same Date format, but not tested for edge case scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change Hour,Minute,seconds and milliseconds attributes of time object like this.

```
var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    date.setMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get the string in a format familiar to people

```
// Date String returned in format yyyy-mm-dd
function getYesterdayString(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // fix 0 index
    return (date.getYear() + 1900) + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Library called node-datetime

```
var datetime = require('node-datetime');
var dt = datetime.create();
// 7 day in the past
dt.offsetInDays(-1);
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score -1):

Extract yesterday's date from today

```
//optimized way 
        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
        console.log(yesterday) // log yesterday's date 


//in-detail way 
        var today = new Date();
        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
        console.log(yesterday) // log yesterday's date
```

Answer (score -3):

Date class will give the current system date and current_ date - 1 will give the yesterday date.

Eg:

```
var d = new Date(); // Today!
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // Yesterday!
```