# Get one week before date compared to todays date in Node js in Mysql Format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to get the past date precisely one week from current date in sql format in node js .I tried this -[How to get yesterday date in node.js backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912523/how-to-get-yesterday-date-in-node-js-backend) but it does'nt seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Library called node-datetime

```
var datetime = require('node-datetime');
var dt = datetime.create();
// 7 day in the past
dt.offsetInDays(-7);
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
console.log(formatted)
```