# Date duration / date subtraction calculations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

The requirement is to calculate the result of subtracting a certain number of days from a given date.

For example, if the given date is "3-Nov-2015 "and if the duration is 5 days, the result should be "29-Oct-2015".

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I use http://momentjs.com/ for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Can't you use the answer provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript Did you search for an answer before posting?

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) library:

```
moment("3-Nov-2015", "DD-MMM-YYYY").subtract(5, 'days').format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

Or, more modularly:

```
function getPrevDate(startDate, numDays, dateFormat) {
  var dateFormat = dateFormat || "DD-MMM-YYYY"; // default date format
  return moment(startDate, dateFormat).subtract(numDays, 'days').format(dateFormat);
}
```

`getPrevDate("3-Nov-2015", 5)` returns `"29-Oct-2015"`