# pickaday.js user can select any date from next 15 days only

Tags: javascript

I'm using `pickaday.js`. I want the user to only be able to select a date between today and the next 15 dates. I have set current date by using javascript `new Date()` function but I'm unable to figure out how to set max day to next 15 days only. Please check my code below

HTML

```
<input value="" id="datepicker" type="text" readonly>
```

SCRIPT

```
 var currentDate = new Date();
        var day = currentDate.getDate();
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

 var picker = new Pikaday(
            {
              field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
              firstDay: 1,
              format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
              minDate: new Date(year, month, day),
              maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31)
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the `maxDate` like this

```
maxDate: new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do it with setDate :

```
var minDate = new Date(year, month, day) ;
var maxDate = new Date() ;
maxDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+15) ;
```

Regarding [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var someDate = new Date(); 
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 15)
var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  firstDay: 1,
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: someDate 
});
```

That will add 15 days to your calendar.

Comment: Thanks for help.. but how to define `someDate`... means how to calculate 15 days from today date

Comment: new Date() gives you todays date. Then we add 15 days to it.