# Javascript get 3 day before from date formate '2017-11-10' without time

Tags: javascript

I have a variable has a value of `2017-11-10` and like to get 3 days before from `2017-11-10` which is `2017-11-7`

Seems like it only works if you have entire timestamp. However, I removed time from my timestamp.

```
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
```

Is there any ways to do this without time?

Comment: You would parse the string to get a `Date` object (one way or another), then set the date to current minus 3, then format the `Date` as a string without time.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript.  You could also see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp regarding date formats in javascript.  Essentially you should have no problem with the format of YYYY-MM-DD that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few options to get a date string in yyyy-m-d format:

```js
var d = new Date( new Date("2017-11-10" + "z") - 3 * 864e5 ) // specify Zulu time zone to avoid conversion to local time

console.log( d.toJSON().slice(0, 10) ) // "2017-11-07"

console.log( d.toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace('-0', '-') ) // "2017-11-7"

console.log( d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getUTCDate() ) // "2017-11-7"
```

---

Timezone information can be added to the date string to avoid conversion to local time:

```js
console.log( new Date("2000-1-2") ) // "2000-01-01T05:00:00.000Z" ("T05:" because converted to local time)

// correct "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
console.log( new Date("2000-01-02") )   
console.log( new Date("2000-1-2 Z") )  
console.log( new Date("2000-1-2 GMT") ) 
console.log( new Date("2000-1-2 UTC") ) 

console.log( new Date("2000-1-2 z-1234") ) // "2000-01-02T12:34:00.000Z" ha ..
```

Comment: @Ohsik if any of the dates are not in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, see the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just init your date string to javascript Date as below example

```
let d = new Date(2017, 10, 10);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-3);
```