# Javascript current day minus 2 weeks in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to get the date of constantly changing two weeks back so from today two weeks back in YYYY-MM-DD format. I got it with this code snippet that works, but is there a better way?

Thanks!!!

```js
const twoWeeksBack = new Date(Date.now() - 12096e5).toISOString().slice(0, 10);

console.log(twoWeeksBack);
```

Comment: This is duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend **[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)** for anything to do with time/date conversion.

Simply `.subtract(2, 'weeks')` and then `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`:

```js
const twoWeeksBack = moment(new Date()).subtract(2, 'weeks').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(twoWeeksBack);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can use libraries, [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is very useful for date manipulation

```
moment().subtract(2, 'weeks').format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```