# How to change current date -7 days from now - [PersianDatepicker]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, persian-calendar

I am using `Babakhani` `Datepicker` and actually i have done `substract` thing from `datepicker` but it does not work on this , so i want to cast `-7` days from `currentdate`

I have done it on `console` Like this

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var days = 7;
nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - days);
var mamat = nowDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log(mamat);
```

but as i am using `PERSIAN` not `GREGORIAN` i cant convert it

I have to use it on this

```
$(".persianDate").pDatepicker();
```

today date is `1/13/2019`
and i want it to be `1/7/2019`

`Babakhani` Source :

```
http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/options/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
// Woud log:
// 1/12/2019
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('fa-IR'));
// Woud log:
// ۱۳۹۷/۱۰/۲۲
```

If you want to set the calendar, then you can pass the desired calendar as an argument to the toLocaleDateString method, [as per the MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) For example, passing 'ar-EG' will result in Arabic digits.

Possible duplicate of [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript).

Comment: It is ok but i dont know how to pass or define it to $(".persianDate").pDatepicker();

Comment: I have no experience with that library, but if you pass 'fa-IR' as an argument to the toLocaleDateString method it'll convert it to Solar Hijri. I updated the answer to reflect this. Also, check the MDN doc I provided to you if you have any further doubts, this is among the information.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.