# How to print 14 days ago based off current date using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using this to print the current date:

```js
let date = (( new Date()).getMonth()+ 1 ) +  "-" + ( new Date()).getDate() + "-" + ( new Date()).getFullYear()

console.log(date)
```

I want to be able to print the date fourteen days ago using a similar format. Can this be done using javascript?

Comment: Replace `new Date` with a date 14 days ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Is a date 14*24 hours ago ok? (Not the same as as 14 days)

Comment: I believe a date 14*24 hours would be ok. It would just need to work when going back to the previous month. Also would be nice if it was in "MM-DD-YYYY"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for that :

```js
let calculatedDate = moment().add(-14, 'day').format("M-DD-YYYY")

document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML = calculatedDate
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<h3></h3>
```