# Subtract a day from a date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to subtract a day from this date format yyyy-mm-dd (string) but can't figure out any way to achieve that using javascript.

What I tried

```js
dateISO = new Date(form.date);
dateISO.setDate(dateISO.getDate() - 1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you explicitly state what the problem is? What result do you get and what are you expecting? What is the value of `form.date`?

Comment: value of ```form.date``` is a string example: 2020-12-04

Comment: Your code works, even with that string. What is your specific problem? Though you need to declare dateISO: `const dateISO = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works.

```js
const form = {date: '2020-12-04'}
const dateISO = new Date(form.date);
console.log(dateISO);
dateISO.setDate(dateISO.getDate() - 1);
console.log(dateISO);
```

Comment: Since timestamps in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, it would be better to use UTC methods: `dateISO.setUTCDate(dateISO.getUTCDate() - 1)`.

Comment: Agreed, I was merely illustrating that the OP's code worked without errors as submitted.