# Subtract 1 day from date input box and submit using button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to collect 2 dates using input boxes ids From and To. I would like to subtract 1 day from the date value received using "FROM" text box and pass that new value to the button click event.

The code below works to push values received from the input box. However, i wish to subtract 1 day and pass on the same.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

From : <input type="date" class="form-control" id="From" placeholder="From" aria-label="From">
To : <input type="date" class="form-control" id="To" placeholder="To" aria-label="To">

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='@SITE@/TDL-Test-code.aspx?FromTo=(Date ge datetime%27'+FD+'T00:00:00.000Z%27) and (Date le datetime%27'+ document.getElementById('To').value+'T23:59:00.000Z%27)';" value="Submit" />
```

Edit:
Following is my moment JS function

```
var oldfrom = document.getElementById('From').value;
newdate = moment(oldfrom).subtract(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var FD = newdate;
```

Comment: That's a lot of inline javascript. Why not just put that in a javascript `<script>` tag or a javascript file?

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. I will improve the code as a fix becomes available. Thank you.

Comment: Invalid date error received as i submit the values

Comment: There are many examples here on SO showing how to subtract a day in JS, and plenty of those without needing moment or jQuery, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/how-to-subtract-days-from-a-plain-date).  Then to set your `To` value just use `document.getElementById('To').value = ...`. BTW none of your code uses jQuery, why load it?

Comment: Appreciate the response. This is a small part of the code which needs fixing. There are few parts that require jquery.

Comment: Fair enough. I am just always curious when I see jQuery loaded and then not used.  There is a cost in loading it, and IMO mixing plain JS/jQuery code is harder to grok and maintain, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed with solution below.

```js
document.getElementById("From_Local").oninput = function() {
  var dateLocal = document.getElementById("From_Local").value;
  var dateUTC = moment.utc(dateLocal).subtract(4, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  document.getElementById("From_UTC").value = dateUTC;
}
```

```html
From:<input name="From" required type="date" id="From_Local">
<input type="hidden" id="From_UTC">
To:<input name="To" required type="date" id="To">

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='SITE_URL?FromTo=(Date%20ge%20datetime%27'+ document.getElementById('From_UTC').value+'T00:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Date%20le%20datetime%27'+ document.getElementById('To').value+'T00:00:00.000Z%27)';" value="Submit" />
```