# JS minus 1 day from date input

Tags: javascript, html, json

Without having to worry about timezone or anything, what's the fastest and best way to -1 day from the input=date on my form within JS, covert to string as YYYY-MM-DD so it can be parsed and used to post to API etc?
[image]

My date_to var as you can see from my date_to_selector.val() prints the string "YYYY-MM-DD" - I need to minus 1 day from this string in a new variable

Here is my code from the date input "Date To":

```
<input type="date" name="date_to" />
var date_to_selector         = $(this).parent().find("input[name=date_to]");
var date_to = date_to_selector.val();
```

I've looked into this and many suggest moment.JS or toISOString but I don't want to have to worry about timezones etc.

Comment: To substract 1 day see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/how-to-subtract-days-from-a-plain-date

Comment: if you get your date in ```yyyy-mm-dd``` format then minus 1 day should be ```yyyy-mm-dd-1``` and handle if day value is 0 or 9. nothing complicated. Am I missing something?

Comment: @seriously - Yes. Doesn't work like that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the input's `valueAsDate` property, then set its date to the day of the selected date minus 1:

```js
$('input[type="date"]').change(function(){
  const date = $(this).prop('valueAsDate')
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
  const res = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}).split('/').join('-');
  console.log(res)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="date_to" />
```

Comment: How can I make the output YYYY-MM-DD string only without T00:00:00.000Z?

Comment: This then includes toISOString which means taking into consideration timezones, UTC etc. I've gotten as far as: toLocaleString("en-CA") which outputs into a string correctly however, includes time info too

Comment: @AG9 OK. I've updated my answer again to use `toLocaleString`.

Comment: how bout using moment js its as easy as ```moment().subtract(1, 'days')``` @Spectric

Comment: @seriously Sounds like a great idea. Not sure if OP wants to use a library though.

Comment: without library ```new Date(Date.now() - 8.64e7)``` @Spectric

Comment: @Spectric - Perfect, exactly what I needed thanks! 
with toLocaleString - do I have to worry about timezones etc?

Comment: @AG9 As long as you specify the timezone in the first parameter (like I did in my solution, `en-US`), then you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: I'm returning the data exactly as needed, but still getting a parsing error "unexpected end of JSON input" - any ideas?

Comment: @AG9 The error probably isn't caused by the date parsing. Looks like you're using `JSON.parse` on something that's not valid JSON. Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: @spectric - is it possible to IM you somewhere to discuss?

Comment: @AG9 We can discuss in this SO chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239429/room-for-spectric-and-ag9